# how to extract this pattern with SQL BIGQUERY?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

From this clause:
b-12345_xx_aa_bbb_xsx-latam_jan_11_a12

I want to extract with REGEXP_EXTRACT:

- b-12345
- xx
- aa
- bbb

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
select col,
  parts[offset(0)], 
  parts[safe_offset(1)], 
  parts[safe_offset(2)], 
  parts[safe_offset(3)]
from your_table, unnest([struct(split(col, '_') as parts)])
```

if applied to dummy data in your question - output is

[image]